# Can I get Lang value from URL into my page's HTML lang attribute

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I m working on validation of my portal which is two languages English and french. I want to specify lang attribute in the  tag. (i.e .....localhost:40630/?lang=fr) IS there any way to fetch the lang value form URL and place it into HTML lang attribute.

My application is in MVC4 razor engine.

Comment: you can get it via jquery if it is needed on client side

Comment: can u pleas explain it more... and den how can i use it in place of HTML lang attrbute

Comment: This can be done with client-side scripting that inspects the query string, extracts a component from it, and then changes the DOM by adding an attribute to the `html` element. But what do you expect to gain by that? It will not have any impact on page rendering in any normal situation, except in some screen readers.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it is what yo want but with javascript you could do something like this:

**JS**

```
//This function should be use to get the lang query string value from the URL.
function getQueryString(variable) {
    var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var vars = query.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
        var pair = vars[i].split('=');
        if (decodeURIComponent(pair[0]).toLowerCase() == variable.toLowerCase()) {
            return decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);
        }
    }

    return null;
}

//Then you get the html element and set to it the lang attribute.
var html = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0];
html.setAttribute('lang', getQueryString('lang'));
```

Comment: thanks for the answer...m trying to fix it wid ur solution... but is it possible thru some other mean too? I mean to ask is it possible to declare the lang attribute based on the lang of the page other than fetching it from url. My portal is in two language english and french... nd i want something lyk dis...<html lang="en" xml:lang="en"> or <html lang="fr" xml:lang="fr">